# Sendkeys Global Hotkey only working once?

Tags: c#, sendkeys, global-hotkey

So for fun I'm messing about with Global Hotkeys using this resource (http://www.fluxbytes.com/csharp/how-to-register-a-global-hotkey-for-your-application-in-c/)

I've got it working fine sending keys using the following:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
     base.WndProc(ref m);
     if (m.Msg == 0x0312)
     {
          SendKeys.Send("ayy lmao" + "{ENTER}");
     }
}
```

Now when I use the hotkey in Notepad, I can do this as many times as I like. But when I do it in Chrome, it will only sendkeys once after pressing the hotkey, and then it will not do it again!

Not only will it not do it in Chrome, it also won't do it in Steam either!

The strange thing is it still works and will send as many times as I want in Notepad...

Can anyone help me out?